# crypto.randomBytes sync vs async performance

Tags: node.js, performance, microservices, cryptojs

[crypto.randomBytes](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) has both sync and async functionality. I have created a library which has a method to generate 16 character unique transactionId using crypto.randomBytes for microservice-to-microservice communication. It's used by 100+ microservices. The microservices are powered by nodejs.

Wanted to understand should I use async one or sync one as when I benchmarked both, I got surprising result.

Async approach:

```
% cat asyncRandomBytes.js 
crypto = require("crypto");
for (var i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
  crypto.randomBytes(16, function(err) {});
}
% time node asyncRandomBytes.js

node asyncRandomBytes.js  20.79s user 13.67s system 210% cpu 16.336 total
```

Sync approach:

```
% cat syncRandomBytes.js 
crypto = require("crypto");
for (var i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
  crypto.randomBytes(16);
}
% time node syncRandomBytes.js 

node syncRandomBytes.js  3.92s user 1.41s system 132% cpu 4.017 total
```

The async one is taking more time. Should I use async one in production where we have multiple API calls (20K rpm per service) on a single core machine?

Comment: 4 seconds for 2.000.000 calls, so 2 microseconds per sync call. I doubt that will noticable.

Comment: I did this benchmarking on my machine which have a higher config

Comment: Consider why you would run the async version: to prevent blocking the event loop, mostly. Then consider how long the sync version will block the event loop. Judging by your benchmark: not a noticeable amount. Even if your servers are 10 times slower, I don't think 20 microseconds will be noticeable either.

Comment: cool, I'll do benchmarking on the server then. The difference is more btw, servers are like t2.micro instance (1GB ram, 1 vCPU) while my system, where I ran this benchmark is (Macbook Pro 16" - 16GB Ram, Core-i7, 6 cores)

Answer (score 0):

**Async**

If you get more requests then you can process in time it can lead the nodejs server to crash. (Out of Memory, or Hanging at 100% CPU because of the GC)

You can implement a limiter that prevents open new async calls so that the process cant crash but this can lead to timeouts.

**Sync**

If you use sync and get more requests then you can process it can lead to timouts but the server will be alive.

**Alternative**

You should consider to use more instances too share the load over multiple CPU cores or if you only have one core it can also reduce the load for the GC. (Use a process manager of your choice)

> Tipp: For Node.js you can [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) as Process Manager

*GC = Garbage Collector*